# How can I modify the netcat command line to send many requests at once

Tags: linux, network-programming, netcat

Let's suppose there is a TCP server listening to port 8080.
The client connects and sends, for example, a "hello" message after using the Netcat command:

```
nc localhost:8080
```

How can I send the "hello" message 1000 times without me being typing? Can I access the Netcat file and add a 'for' or 'while' loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to modify `nc`; just pipe your input to it: `yes hello | head -n 1000 | nc localhost:8080`.

Comment: It is not working

`yes hello | head -n 1000 | nc localhost:8080
This is nc from the netcat-openbsd package. An alternative nc is available
in the netcat-traditional package.
usage: nc [-46bCDdhjklnrStUuvZz] [-I length] [-i interval] [-O length]
   [-P proxy_username] [-p source_port] [-q seconds] [-s source]
   [-T toskeyword] [-V rtable] [-w timeout] [-X proxy_protocol]
   [-x proxy_address[:port]] [destination] [port]
`

Comment: you meant like this 

`nc localhost:8080 |yes hello | head -n 1000`

it is working now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an app that has a IN_ServerSocket for incoming data and a OUT_ServerSocket for outgoing data. Multiple clients can connect to both ServerSockets.
The purpose is to forward all incoming data to every client connected to OUT_ServerSocket.
In principle I will have only one client on IN_ServerSocket.

This client will send the data forever with delay:

```
while sleep 0.05; do echo "DATA_2_xxxxxx"; done | nc 127.0.0.1 22221
```

To see the data on the other side:

```
nc 127.0.0.1 22222
```